# what happens with FirebaseAuth in flutter if the app is stopped or running in background?

Tags: firebase, dart, firebase-authentication, flutter

Sorry, I am back with a bug again. I am actually trying to optimise my firebase database and wanted to know how the firebase authentication works when the app is running.

1.so the question is how long does a connection persist once we get an instance?

2.what happens to the instance which we have already when the app is in the background or killed by the user?

3.what is the optimised way to go about having a connection with firebase ? is it better if we have a persistent connection or creating new instances?

4. if persistent connection is better then how can we achieve this functionality in flutter mobile apps.

Many thanks,
Mahi.